# I accidentally locked my linux root user and now I can't login in

Tags: linux, ubuntu, aws, mobaxterm

I accidentally added my root user to my sftp group using command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G sftp ubuntu
```

And now everytime I tried to login my linux server it shows this error: [image]

I do not have any other users in the server. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with an AWS EC2 instance, you really only have one option for recovery: stopping the instance, mounting the EBS volume to another EC2 instance, and then manually modifying the /etc/group file to remove the `ubuntu` user from the `sftp` group.

AWS provides instructions on how to mount the EBS volume onto another EC2 instance [at this documentation link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-attaching-volume.html). In the interests of fighting link-rot the steps are:

> **To attach an EBS volume to an instance using the console**
>
> 1. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/
> 2. In the navigation pane, choose Volumes.
> 3. Select the volume to attach and choose Actions, Attach volume.
>
> **Note**
>
> **You can attach only volumes that are in the Available state.**
>
> 4. For Instance, enter the ID of the instance or select the instance from the list of options.
>
> **Note**
>
> **The volume must be attached to an instance in the same Availability Zone.**
>
> **If the volume is encrypted, it can only be attached to instance types that support Amazon EBS encryption. For more information, see Amazon EBS encryption.**
>
> 5. For Device name, enter a supported device name for the volume. This device name is used by Amazon EC2. The block device driver for the instance might assign a different device name when mounting the volume. For more information, see Device names on Linux instances.
> 6. Choose Attach volume.
> 7. Connect to the instance and mount the volume. For more information, see Make an Amazon EBS volume available for use on Linux.

After you have removed the `ubuntu` user from the `sftp` group, you can disconnect the volume from the EC2 instance you were working on, start up the original EC2 instance that had the error, and SSH to it normally.

Comment: Out of interest how do you know this is AWS?

Comment: @roaima Running `whois` for the IP address displayed in the picture as the SSH connection target will indicate it is operated by "Amazon AWS Network Operations". Also, anyone that's been using AWS themselves a lot might recognize the IP address range on sight.

Comment: @roaima telecoM has it right in the second part, I was briefly a CSE for AWS so I got pretty familiar with their most popular IP spaces. What hinted at me was the username was `ubuntu`, that's a very AWS thing, and I've only seen it also in the Ubuntu installation disc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't login as root. Login as your administrative user and use `sudo -s` to get a root shell.

Failing that, boot a [rescue image](https://www.system-rescue.org/) and use that to reset root's groups membership